# Tibco Rendezvous: How to create complex Msg Responses?

Tags: java, tibco-rv

I'm building a Tibco Rendezvous message (8.4.5) with its JAVA API.

The reference I have got are tibrvlisten sniff that gave me only a text representation of what is wanted from the system is expecting a Tibco Rendezvous message from my application.

So, basically I'm in the need to write Java Code using Tibrv API, to generate the following output message (the following examples are only message portions):

**EXAMPLE1**

> ...^prefixList^={
>   default="/tibco/public/class/ae/NESPIntl/NESPAdapter/Request"
>   1="/tibco/public/class/ae/NESPIntl/Common"
>   2="/tibco/public/sequence/ae/NESPAdapter"
>   3="/tibco/public/union/ae/NESPAdapter" 4="/tibco/public/scalar/ae"
>   }...

What kind of data structure must be used here? How should I represent a value pair of this kind?

**EXAMPLE2**

> ...^data^={^class^="Send_Message_Result" RESPONSE={^idx^=1
>   ^class^="HosaMessageReport_Set" ^1^={^idx^=2
>   ^class^="HosaMessageReport" USERADDRESS={^idx^=2 ^class^="Address"
>   PLAN=5 ADDRSTRING="3345205381" NAME="" PRESENTATION= SCREENING=0
>   SUBADDRESSSTRING=""} RESPONSE=1 TIMESTAMP="200716161352"}}
>   SUBJECTIDENTITY="" JOBID=29525108}...

This is the most complex part of message response. How should I set "class" here? Is it something that is automatically detected by Tibco Rendezvous once the Java structure that is provided is declared as TibrvMsg subclass? Or is it a parameter to be set like all the others?

Anyone has field experience on this matter? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Kind Regards,
Pierluigi

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have some way of listening to messages from the application, since you can use tibrvlisten.  So, instead of using tibrvlisten, why don't you write Java code to receive the messages in your Java application.  That would show you exactly what the RV messages should look like.